# Trying to solve the Kattis task "Coast" - can't figure it why I am slightly off

Tags: c++

I am basically trying to make a program that given an NxM map of zeroes and ones will determine the length of coast, not including inland lake coasts.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Coast {
   int n, m;
   vector<vector<int>> vmap;
   bool isLake = true;

   // Starts recursive methods
   void lakeCheckMain(int y, int x){
      vmap[y][x] = 10;
      if(vmap[y-1][x] == 0){
         lakeCheck(y-1, x);
      }
      if(vmap[y+1][x] == 0){
         lakeCheck(y+1, x);
      }
      if(vmap[y][x-1] == 0){
         lakeCheck(y, x-1);
      }
      if(vmap[y][x+1] == 0){
         lakeCheck(y, x+1);
      }

      if(isLake){
         lakeColor(y, x);
      }
      else{
         lakeDeColor(y, x);
      }
   }

   // Assign value 4 to all connected water
   void lakeColor(int y, int x){
      vmap[y][x] = 4;
      if(vmap[y-1][x] == 0 || vmap[y-1][x] == 10){
         lakeColor(y-1, x);
      }
      if(vmap[y+1][x] == 0 || vmap[y+1][x] == 10){
         lakeColor(y+1, x);
      }
      if(vmap[y][x-1] == 0 || vmap[y][x-1] == 10){
         lakeColor(y, x-1);
      }
      if(vmap[y][x+1] == 0 || vmap[y][x+1] == 10){
         lakeColor(y, x+1);
      }
   }

   // Assigns 0 to all checked water fields
   void lakeDeColor(int y, int x){
      //cout << "lets decolor" << endl;
      vmap[y][x] = 0;
      if(vmap[y-1][x] == 10){
         lakeDeColor(y-1, x);
      }
      if(vmap[y+1][x] == 10){
         lakeDeColor(y+1, x);
      }
      if(vmap[y][x-1] == 10){
         lakeDeColor(y, x-1);
      }
      if(vmap[y][x+1] == 10){
         lakeDeColor(y, x+1);
      }
   }

   // Checks neightboring fields for what and stops if edge is reached
   void lakeCheck(int y, int x){
      if((y < 1) || (x < 1) || (x > m) || (y > n) || !isLake){
         isLake = false;
      }
      else{
         //cout << y << x << " checking around me" << endl;
         if(vmap[y-1][x] == 0){
            vmap[y][x] = 10;
            lakeCheck(y-1, x);
         }
         if(vmap[y+1][x] == 0){
            vmap[y][x] = 10;
            lakeCheck(y+1, x);
         }
         if(vmap[y][x-1] == 0){
            vmap[y][x] = 10;
            lakeCheck(y, x-1);
         }
         if(vmap[y][x+1] == 0){
            vmap[y][x] = 10;
            lakeCheck(y, x+1);
         }
      }
   }


   public:
   int checker(){
      double result;
      cin >> n >> m;

      //Map init
      vmap.resize(n+2);
      for(int i = 0 ; i < n+2 ; ++i){
           vmap[i].resize(m+2);
      }

      // -1, m to 0
      // n, -1 to 0
      for (size_t i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
            vmap[0][i] = 0;
            vmap[n+1][i] = 0;
      }
      for (size_t i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            vmap[i][0] = 0;
            vmap[i][m+1] = 0;
      }

      for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         string tempStrng;
         cin >> tempStrng;
         for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            int binVal = tempStrng.at(j) - 48;
            vmap[i+1][j+1] = binVal;
         }
      }

      // Sets all land fields to 4 as well as setting all inland lakes to the value 4
      for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
         for (size_t q = 1; q <= m; q++) {
            if(vmap[i][q] == 1){
               vmap[i][q] = 4;
            }
            else if(vmap[i][q] == 0){
               isLake = true;
               //cout << i << ", " << q << " checking water" << endl;
               lakeCheckMain(i, q);
            }
         }
      }

      /*string resultStr;
      for (size_t i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
         for (size_t q = 1; q < m+1; q++) {
            resultStr += to_string(vmap[i][q]);
         }
         resultStr += "\n";
      }
      cout << resultStr << endl;*/

      //Dynamically goes through the map from top left and looks left and above for other land
      //Skips water
      for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
         for (size_t q = 1; q <= m; q++) {
            if(vmap[i][q] == 0){
               continue;
            }
            if(vmap[i-1][q] != 0){
               vmap[i][q] -= 1;
               vmap[i-1][q] -= 1;
            }
            if(vmap[i][q-1] != 0){
               vmap[i][q] -= 1;
               vmap[i][q-1] -= 1;
            }
         }
      }

      for (size_t i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
         for (size_t q = 0; q <= m; q++) {
            result += vmap[i][q];
         }
      }

      cout << result << endl;
   }
};



int main(){
   Coast c;
   c.checker();
}
```

When I run it on this input:

```
101011100110010000010110010001
111111001011111110101110100001
111111110011100110111011010000
010100110111000110101110001100
001010100110111101011000000011
010100011100000000000100011100
000001111010010110111001010110
110111001111100001100000001010
110101111110001110101101111101
110011000101101001010111000111
110001111011000010010111110001
000111100100011000101111101111
000000001100000000000001101101
101001001011001010010010101111
011101101010010010101111101101
101010100111111101110000010111
110100011100100110011010001100
100110010100000000111001111100
000011010110101000100001110101
011010101011010110110110101011
```

I am getting 302, but I am supposed to get 308. I am aware that this problem by linearly by BFS, but I didn't see that when I started. Now I just want my code to work. Can someone spot the error in my code, before I go crazy.

Comment: Here is a hint. It is good that you know how to write BFS/DFS. Just add an additional artificial water frame to the rectangle. Simply run BFS/DFS from (0,0) by water cells. Every time you find a land cell neighbouring the current water cell increment the counter. There is no need to think about the lakes.

Comment: Your question is off-topic unless you include the *code in the body of the question*. Off-site links are frowned upon since they have a tendency to go bad.

Answer (score 0):

I am updating my answer..

I just run this sample you gave me with my code (Java) and the result it gives is 302.

Also my code pasts the coast test in kattis.

Why do you think the result should be 308? Did you go through it by hand?